# Persist a Hyperlink's Style after mouse has moved away

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

Is it possible to persist the look of a 'hovered' hyperlink even after the mouse has moved away from it?  I want to keep the user's attention on the hyperlink -- or at least have them able to see what it was, standing out from the rest of the text -- for a few seconds after they've left it. Ideally it would fade slowly back to normal.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can catch the mouse move events and change the style of the component there rather than using the built-in hover designations. You can use effects to make it glow, fade, or bounce.

Cheers